# What's the best way to integrate data from Kafka to HBase&Hive?

Tags: hive, apache-kafka, hbase, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to this topic. I generate a lot of data in Kafka with time series data. And I need to send this data in a database either HBase or Hive. However,  I read that it is good practice to use Hive and Hbase together. 
Kafka can connect to HBase and also to Hive with Kafka Confluent.
What is the best practice to send data from Kafka to HBase and then make a Hive HBase Integration or send data from Kafka to Hive and then make a integration with HBase?
Kafka -> Hbase -> Hive
or
Kafka -> Hive -> Hbase
And after that send this data to Spark.

Comment: What exactly do you need Hive for if you can send data directly to HBase and query that with Spark?

Comment: I want to do some analytics on the different levels. Firstly more easily query make in Hbase&Hive, for more difficulty analytics like a machine learning in Spark.

Comment: Okay, then what's the problem exactly? The best practice depends very specifically on your own use case...